# Oracle PL/SQL Swapping a for loop for dynamic SQL, assistance with syntax changes

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a for loop, here:

```
BEGIN

for rws in (

select /*+parallel (4)*/ a.owner,a.table_name, round(sum(b.sum_bytes),2) TOT_OBJECT_SIZE_MB, EST_ONE_ROW_MB
from dba_tables@DB1 a, MV_PRD_SEG_DATA b
where a.table_name = b.segment_name
and a.table_name in
(select table_name from MV_PDU_TABLE where driver_table is null)
and a.owner in (select distinct productionschema from MV_PDU_TABLE c)
group by a.owner,a.table_name
order by a.table_name
)
loop
```

Data is pulled out of the loop as follows by referencing rws. :

```
execute immediate' select /*+parallel (4)*/ count(*) from ' ||rws.owner||'.'||rws.table_name || '@' || dblink into TOTAL_ROW_COUNT;
```

I now have to change some of the hard coded table references in the select statement to variables. (I will be declaring these earlier in the code.)

As I understand it, I must now switch to dynamic SQL.

In doing so, you can see here how the hard coded tables are now referred to as variables:

```
BEGIN

v_sql1 := 'select /*+parallel (4)*/ a.owner,a.table_name, round(sum(b.sum_bytes),2) TOT_OBJECT_SIZE_MB, EST_ONE_ROW_MB
from dba_tables@NAB1 a, '|| v_Mv_name ||' b
where a.table_name = b.segment_name
and a.table_name in
(select table_name from '|| v_Mv_name ||' where driver_table is null)
and a.owner in (select distinct productionschema from '|| v_Mv_name ||' c)
group by a.owner,a.table_name
order by a.table_name';
```

The issue is... how do I now manage getting the data out of the loop? I think I would loop, just using the variable containing the SQL?:

```
for rws in (v_sql1)

loop
```

If so, what would now go here?

```
execute immediate' select /*+parallel (4)*/ count(*) from ' <NO_IDEA_HOW_TO_REFERENCE_THE_DATA_IN_THE_LOOP_NOW> ' into TOTAL_ROW_COUNT;
```

Comment: You should prefer ANSI join syntax, i.e. `from dba_tables@NAB1 a JOIN '|| v_Mv_name ||' b ON a.table_name = b.segment_name`

Comment: There is no reason for DISTINCT in `and a.owner in (select distinct ...` - just skip the `DISTINCT`, the performance might be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use a RefCursor:

```
declare
   cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
   owner varchar2(30); 
   table_namevarchar2(30); 
   TOT_OBJECT_SIZE_MB number; 
   EST_ONE_ROW_MB number; 
   TOTAL_ROW_COUNT integer;
   v_sql1 varchar2(10000);

begin

v_sql1 := 'select /*+parallel (4)*/ a.owner,a.table_name, round(sum(b.sum_bytes),2) TOT_OBJECT_SIZE_MB, EST_ONE_ROW_MB
from dba_tables@NAB1 a, '|| v_Mv_name ||' b
where a.table_name = b.segment_name
and a.table_name in
(select table_name from '|| v_Mv_name ||' where driver_table is null)
and a.owner in (select distinct productionschema from '|| v_Mv_name ||' c)
group by a.owner,a.table_name
order by a.table_name';

   open cur for v_sql1;
   loop
      fetch cur into owner, table_name, TOT_OBJECT_SIZE_MB, EST_ONE_ROW_MB;
      exit when cur%NOTFOUND;
      execute immediate' select /*+parallel (4)*/ count(*) from '||table_name into TOTAL_ROW_COUNT;
   end loop;
end;
```

Usually a `BULK COLLECT` provides better performance. However, as you run a dedicated query for each record I don't think you will notice any difference in the performance.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you so much!! :-)

Answer (score 2):

You may do a `BULK COLLECT`  into collection of record you wish to return and then loop through the collection.

You may be able to use this example readily into your script.

```
DECLARE
 TYPE sizerec is RECORD ( owner dba_tables.owner%type, 
  table_name dba_tables.table_name%type,
  tot_object_size_mb number);
  TYPE srectab  is TABLE OF  sizerec;
  srec srectab;
  l_tab_name varchar2(40) := 'dba_tables';
BEGIN


EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
'SELECT a.owner,a.table_name,round(SUM(b.bytes),2) tot_object_size_mb
  FROM '||l_tab_name||' a
JOIN dba_segments b ON a.table_name = b.segment_name where rownum < 10
GROUP BY a.owner,a.table_name ' BULK COLLECT INTO srec;

for i in srec.first..srec.last 
loop
  dbms_output.put_line(srec(i).owner||','||srec(i).table_name
                                    ||','||srec(i).tot_object_size_mb);
end loop;

END;
/
```

Output

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SYS,BOOTSTRAP$,65536
SYS,FILE$,65536
SYS,OBJERROR$,65536
SYS,UNDO$,65536
SYS,PROXY_DATA$,65536
SYS,OBJ$,10485760
SYS,PROXY_ROLE_DATA$,65536
SYS,OBJAUTH$,2097152
SYS,CON$,262144
```